# Xcode Number pad with decimal error

Tags: xcode, decimal, textfield, keypad

In xcode when I turn on the decimal pad keyboard option in the .xib for my textfield, and I run the application, I receive this error:

```
Jun 13 01:22:38 Nicholas-Gibsons-iPhone Quick Utilities[1009] <Error>: 
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This 
application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby 
contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is 
a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

If you have any idea what this really means, you would be a lot of help! Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you running ios7 beta? I get the same error when I show a UIActionSheet in the ios7 beta; works fine in ios6.1 though.

Comment: Yes! I have been to the developer forums, and Apple has now fixed the bug! I am sorry that I posted this here, I was not aware at the time.

Comment: NicholasGibson - If you think the solution will be useful to others, have @Zemm post it as an "answer", so it is more visible. If not, you can delete the thread.

Comment: This issue still there in UIwebView, When i tap on webview which has editable div keyboard open, and then double tap on webview get bunch of errors like this, CGContextSetFillColorWithColor
CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0

Answer (score 1):

try the following :

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are using **context** anywhere - if so rename it anywhere it occurs.